# C++ Travis CI and Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, travis-ci

I am trying to configure my project on GitHub using continuous integration and would like to use Travis CI to do so. However, I am getting a build error with the current configuration of my travis.yml. My project uses Qt5, SQLite, and is in C++.

This is the yml:

```
language: cpp

compiler: gcc

before_install:
 - sudo apt-get update -qq
 - sudo apt-get install -qq sqlite3 qt5-dev-tools

before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake

script: make
```

I am new to this and I tried reading up on the documentation on their site, but I'm still having an issue understanding it. If anyone has an example, I would greatly appreciate it. OS is Windows.

Error:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
>   The command "make && make test" exited with 2.

Comment: What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
The command "make && make test" exited with 2.

Comment: cmake has failed then.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that CMake has a non-intuitive error reporting here:

```
before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake
```

It returns success, although it hasn't configured anything in the `build/` directory because it didn't know where the sources are.

Try `cmake ..` instead. Or `cmake <your source directory>`